# How to create multiple tables for each category in existing table column in Big Query?

Tags: google-bigquery

I have category column in my existing table column and I need to create a separate table for each unique category. How can I do this in Big Query?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the python SDK for [BigQuery](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/quickstarts/quickstart-client-libraries). Here is an example you can use:

```
from google.cloud import bigquery

#Initiate the client
client = bigquery.Client()

#Load the dataset in which you are going to store the table
dataset_ref = client.dataset('{dataset}')

#Create the Query which is going to get the values
QUERY = (
    'SELECT DISTINCT {column} FROM `{project-ID}.{dataset}.{table}`'
)

# API request
query_job = client.query(QUERY)

# Wait for the Query to finish and store the query.
rows = query_job.result()

# Define the schema of the new table
schema = [
    bigquery.SchemaField('ExampleField', 'STRING', mode='REQUIRED')
]

#The query is returned as a tuple per row
for value in rows:
        table_ref = dataset_ref.table(value[0])
        table = bigquery.Table(table_ref, schema=schema)
        table = client.create_table(table)
        assert table.table_id == value[0]
```

Keep in mind that a table name can only contain letters (upper or lower case), numbers, and underscores. Thus, you may get an exception if trying to use invalid values.